# Give out each row number per month - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table like this:

```
Month     | Date   
----------------------
May 2019  | 03.05.19
May 2019  | 04.05.19 
May 2019  | 07.05.19   
July 2019 | 03.07.19
July 2019 | 05.07.19 
July 2019 | 06.07.19  
July 2019 | 08.07.19
```

And I wanna have a query that gives out the following.

```
Month     | Date    | Row Count per Month
----------------------
May 2019  | 03.05.19 | 1
May 2019  | 04.05.19 | 2
May 2019  | 07.05.19 | 3
July 2019 | 03.07.19 | 1
July 2019 | 05.07.19 | 2
July 2019 | 06.07.19 | 3
July 2019 | 08.07.19 | 4
```

So it gives out the number of each row per month but I don't know how to do it ( I have many more months and dates than those). I am trying to do it with row_number but can't seem to get it right. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`

```
select *,row_number() over(partition by month order by date) as Row_Count
from tablename
```

Comment: It's not working for me. It says "missing right parenthesis" even though I have ckecked all the parenthesis if any is missing.

Answer (score 2):

use `row_number()`

```
   select t.*, row_number() over( partition by month order by date) rn from table t
```